# Bindestrich bei einer Kombination von Adjektiv und Substantiv: "Hyperbolic and optimal control problems" auf Deutsch

Tags: translation, english-to-german

Ich wurde vorhin gefragt, wie man "hyperbolic and optimal control problems" ins Deutsche übersetzt. Es gibt "hyperbolische Probleme" und "optimale Steuerungsprobleme". Es ist wichtig, dass sich "hyperbolisch" nicht auf "Steuerungsproblem" bezieht, sondern auf "Probleme".

Kann man dies wie im Englischen verbinden und kompakter schreiben? Es mag im vornherein nicht klar sein, dass sich "hyperbolic" nur auf "problems" bezieht, jedoch ist für die meisten in meinem Bereich klar, dass "optimal control" ein Begriff ist.

Ist beispielsweise folgendes möglich?

- hyperbolische- und optimale Steuerungs-Probleme

Es umzukehren könnte helfen, also "optimale Steuerungs- und hyperbolische Probleme", jedoch hätte ich es gerne in der Reihenfolge, sofern möglich.

Comment: Ehrlich gesagt besteht die Mehrdeutigkeit doch auch im Englischen. Es könnte nämlich als _hyperbolic control problems and optimal control problems_ gelesen werden, wenn man _control problems_ als eigenständigen Begriff interpretiert.

Comment: Warum nicht so: _hyperbolische und optimale Steuerungsprobleme_?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Auf der sicheren Seite ist man sicherlich mit der Umkehrung.

Wenn aber die Reihenfolge des englischen Originals beibehalten werden soll,  könnte man sich damit behelfen, die "optimale Steuerung" zu einem Hauptwort "Optimalsteuerung" zusammenzuziehen und dann mit dem Bindestrich zu arbeiten:

> hyperbolische und Optimalsteuerungs-Probleme.